# React JS (Element type is invalid)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components, react-component, react-dom

> I am trying to render my App function in index.js file. But it keeps on showing this error:
> Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.
> Check the render method of `App`.

**App.js**

```
import React from "react";
import { Container, AppBar, Typography, Grow, Grid} from '@material-ui/core';
import memories from './images/memories.png';
import Posts from './components/Posts/Posts';
import Form from './components/Form/Form.js';

const App = () => {
    return(
        <Container maxwidth="lg">
            <AppBar position="static" color="inherit">
                <Typography variant="h2" align="center">Memories</Typography>
                <img src={memories}  alt="memories" height="60"/>
            </AppBar>
            <Grow in>
                <Container>
                    <Grid container justify="space-between" alignItems="stretch" spacing={3}>
                        <Grid item xs={12} sm={7}>
                            <Posts/>
                        </Grid>
                        <Grid item xs={12} sm={4}>
                            <Form/>
                        </Grid>

                    </Grid>
                </Container>
            </Grow>
        </Container>
    )
}
export default App;
```

**index.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

import App from './App';
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Comment: Do `memories`, `Posts`, and `Form` all have default exports?

Comment: I have tried your code on my Codesandbox. but it works well if you import the Post and Form componenet  "https://codesandbox.io/s/elementtype-gyr48?file=/src/App.js"           Check this please

Comment: Hi! Welcome to StackOverflow. This part of the code is fine and the error relates to other components or sections of your code. Can you reproduce it online in the sandbox?

Comment: I guess, the error occurs from other components that you didn't show on the post

Comment: Hi, @USK, did you check?

Comment: @jmargolisvt yes they have default exports.

Comment: @devbluesky111 I have used export default function that you have written in code sandbox but it doesn't bring any change. Also I have checked other imported components. But it is not resolved yet.

Answer (score 0):

I have used `export default function Form(){}` instead of using `export default Form`. The issue got resolved and I don't know the reason. Thanks to everybody who answered.